# Trillian, digsby or Pidgin over Lan?

Tags: instant-messaging, lan, messenger

Does anyone know if it is possible to adapt one of these Messengers in order to use them also over LAN?

Comment: Are you asking if you can create a "local/internal" instant messaging infrastructure of sorts, using just these tools?  Like being able to have employees chat with each other, but not be able to message someone on the internet?  So, not using AOL/GTalk/ICQ services, but instead more of a peer-to-peer localized within some network boundary?

Comment: Using ICQ/MSN/YHOO services but also use the same software to use over LAN (to send messages to other LAN pc's)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely possible with pidgin.

I tried it and it works. You can find tutorials out there that can help you do it.

Theoretically every client that supports bonjour protocol will do the job.

Comment: I searched for it this morning. They spoke about "Bonjour" but nobody tells how to do it. Do you know how?

Comment: You have to make an account and select bonjour protocol.